The provided token program does not match the token program expected by the swap
import { logger } from "../helpers";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as token from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
  TokenSwap,
  TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
  TokenSwapLayout,
  CurveType,
} from "@solana/spl-token-swap";
import fs from "fs";

function loadKeypair(filename: string): web3.Keypair {
  const secret = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename).toString()) as number[];
  const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(secret);
  return web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
}

export class Simulation {
  private wallet = loadKeypair(
    "TM5scABLbymXZc6rnArifaLS1peoUusM2hPqLH7XCSz.json",
  );
  private blockhash: web3.Blockhash;
  private instructions: web3.TransactionInstruction[] = [];
  private signers: web3.Keypair[] = [this.wallet];
  private tokenSwapStateAccount: web3.Keypair;
  private tokenAMint: web3.PublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(
    "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
  );
  private tokenBMint: web3.PublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(
    "4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU", // USDC
  );
  private swapAuthority: web3.PublicKey;
  private poolTokenMint: web3.PublicKey;
  private tokenFeeAccountAddress: web3.PublicKey;
  private tokenATokenAccount: web3.PublicKey;
  private tokenBTokenAccount: web3.PublicKey;
  private tokenAccountPool: web3.Keypair;

  constructor(private readonly connection: web3.Connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
  }

  public async run() {
    await this.setup();
    await this.createSwapPool();
    await this.swap();

    await this.exec();
  }

  public async exec() {
    const message = new web3.TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: this.wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: this.blockhash,
      instructions: this.instructions,
    }).compileToV0Message();
    const tx = new web3.VersionedTransaction(message);

    this.signers = this.signers.filter((s, i) => this.signers.indexOf(s) === i);
    logger.debug("signers: " + this.signers);
    tx.sign(this.signers); // TODO: WHAT TO SIGN

    const txid = await this.connection.sendTransaction(tx);
    logger.debug(txid);
    logger.info(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txid}?cluster=devnet`);
  }

  public async setup() {
    this.blockhash = await this.connection
      .getLatestBlockhash()
      .then((res) => res.blockhash);
    this.instructions = [];
  }

  public async createSwapPool() {
    await this.CreateTokenSwapStateAccount();

    //const [swapAuthority, bump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    const [swapAuthority] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [this.tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
    );
    this.swapAuthority = swapAuthority;
    logger.debug(`swap authority: ${this.swapAuthority.toBase58()}`);

    await this.CreateTokenAccountsForAandB();

    await this.CreatePoolTokenMint();

    await this.CreatePoolTokenAccount();
  }

  private async CreateTokenSwapStateAccount() {
    this.tokenSwapStateAccount = loadKeypair(
      "TSWjtaBCemNH1YswnmiRMAFVq4W4R5DPt1t1rSEd5jR.json",
    );

    const accountInfo = await this.connection.getAccountInfo(
      this.tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey,
    );
    if (accountInfo == null) {
      logger.trace("creating tokenswapstateaccount");
      const rent = await TokenSwap.getMinBalanceRentForExemptTokenSwap(
        this.connection,
      );
      const tokenSwapStateAccountCreationInstruction =
        web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
          newAccountPubkey: this.tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey,
          fromPubkey: this.wallet.publicKey,
          lamports: rent,
          space: TokenSwapLayout.span,
          programId: TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
        });

      this.instructions.push(tokenSwapStateAccountCreationInstruction);
      this.signers.push(this.tokenSwapStateAccount);
    }
  }

  private async CreateTokenAccountsForAandB() {
    const accountInfoA = await this.connection.getAccountInfo(this.tokenAMint);
    const accountInfoB = await this.connection.getAccountInfo(this.tokenBMint);
    const [tokenATokenAccount, taci] =
      await this.getTokenAccountCreationInstruction(
        this.tokenAMint,
        this.swapAuthority,
      );
    const [tokenBTokenAccount, tbci] =
      await this.getTokenAccountCreationInstruction(
        this.tokenBMint,
        this.swapAuthority,
      );

    if (accountInfoA == null) {
      logger.trace("creating tokenaccount A");
      this.instructions.push(taci);
      this.signers.push(this.tokenSwapStateAccount);
    }
    if (accountInfoB == null) {
      logger.trace("creating tokenaccount B");
      this.instructions.push(tbci);
      this.signers.push(this.tokenSwapStateAccount);
    }

    this.tokenATokenAccount = tokenATokenAccount;
    this.tokenBTokenAccount = tokenBTokenAccount;

    logger.debug("token A account: " + tokenATokenAccount.toBase58());
    logger.debug("token B account: " + tokenBTokenAccount.toBase58());
  }

  private async CreatePoolTokenMint() {
    this.poolTokenMint = new web3.PublicKey(
      "LPTZ3WTVk17Nw3ubxizX1VqzWRZyQgW1eh9BoQtSbWo",
    );
  }

  private async CreatePoolTokenAccount() {
    this.tokenAccountPool = web3.Keypair.generate();
    const poolTokenRent = await token.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptAccount(
      this.connection,
    );
    const createTokenAccountPoolInstruction = web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: this.wallet.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: this.tokenAccountPool.publicKey,
      space: token.ACCOUNT_SIZE,
      lamports: poolTokenRent,
      programId: token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    });
    const initializeTokenAccountPoolInstruction =
      token.createInitializeAccountInstruction(
        this.tokenAccountPool.publicKey,
        this.poolTokenMint,
        this.wallet.publicKey,
      );

    this.instructions.push(createTokenAccountPoolInstruction);
    this.instructions.push(initializeTokenAccountPoolInstruction);
    this.signers.push(this.tokenAccountPool);

    const feeOwner = new web3.PublicKey(
      "HfoTxFR1Tm6kGmWgYWD6J7YHVy1UwqSULUGVLXkJqaKN",
    );
    const [tokenFeeAccountAddress, tfaci] =
      await this.getTokenAccountCreationInstruction(
        this.poolTokenMint,
        feeOwner,
      );
    this.tokenFeeAccountAddress = tokenFeeAccountAddress;

    const accountInfoFee = await this.connection.getAccountInfo(
      this.tokenFeeAccountAddress,
    );
    if (accountInfoFee == null) {
      this.instructions.push(tfaci);
      this.signers.push(this.tokenAccountPool);
    }
  }

  public async swap() {
    const tokenSwapInitSwapInstruction = TokenSwap.createInitSwapInstruction(
      this.tokenSwapStateAccount,
      this.swapAuthority,
      this.tokenATokenAccount,
      this.tokenBTokenAccount,
      this.poolTokenMint,
      this.tokenFeeAccountAddress,
      this.tokenAccountPool.publicKey,
      token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
      BigInt(0),
      BigInt(100),
      BigInt(5),
      BigInt(10000),
      BigInt(0),
      BigInt(100),
      BigInt(1),
      BigInt(100),
      CurveType.ConstantProduct,
    );

    this.instructions.push(tokenSwapInitSwapInstruction);
    this.signers.push(this.tokenAccountPool);

    const [tokenATokenAccount1, taci1] =
      await this.getTokenAccountCreationInstruction(
        this.tokenAMint,
        this.wallet.publicKey,
      );
    const [tokenBTokenAccount1, tbci1] =
      await this.getTokenAccountCreationInstruction(
        this.tokenBMint,
        this.wallet.publicKey,
      );
    logger.debug("t1: " + tokenATokenAccount1);
    logger.debug("t2: " + tokenBTokenAccount1);

    this.instructions.push(taci1);
    this.instructions.push(tbci1);

    const swapInstruction = TokenSwap.swapInstruction(
      this.tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey,
      this.swapAuthority,
      this.wallet.publicKey,
      tokenATokenAccount1,
      this.tokenATokenAccount,
      this.tokenBTokenAccount,
      tokenBTokenAccount1,
      this.poolTokenMint,
      this.tokenFeeAccountAddress,
      null,
      token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
      token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      BigInt(10),
      BigInt(0),
    );
    this.instructions.push(swapInstruction);
  }

  private async getTokenAccountCreationInstruction(
    mint: web3.PublicKey,
    swapAuthority: web3.PublicKey,
  ): Promise<[web3.PublicKey, web3.TransactionInstruction]> {
    const tokenAccountAddress = await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mint, // mint
      swapAuthority, // owner
      true, // allow owner off curve
    );

    const tokenAccountInstruction =
      token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        this.wallet.publicKey, // payer
        tokenAccountAddress, // ata
        swapAuthority, // owner
        mint, // mint
      );
    return [tokenAccountAddress, tokenAccountInstruction];
  }
}

When executing I get this error message:
    'Program log: Error: The provided token program does not match the token program expected by the swap',
    'Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw consumed 7015 of 1374896 compute units',
    'Program SwapsVeCiPHMUAtzQWZw7RjsKjgCjhwU55QGu4U1Szw failed: custom program error: 0x18'`

I have mostly used this tutorial as my learning resource. I have been fighting for 4 days now with this problem. I also looked at the rust source code, but haven't been able to come up with a solution.

That program is very old unfortunately, and likely hasn't been updated. If you want to test these bindings, you're better off building and deploying spl-token-swap locally to test correctly
